# Is jQuery.ajax and $.ajax the same?

Tags: ajax

In tutorials can see jQuery.ajax and $.ajax

Like here http://www.thekludge.com/form-auto-save-with-jquery-serialize/

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: 'my_form.php',
```

And here http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-and-when-to-use-jquerys-serialize-method/

```
$.ajax({
url: 'elaboration.php',
```

Please advice is jQuery.ajax and $.ajax is the same?

Answer (score 1):

In general they might be not the same.

`$` can be used and overwritten by some other library that uses it as a global reference to itself.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right but i think in general both are same. because most jquery library avoid these kind of confliction.

Comment: @Manish: the less **assumptions** you're making when you program - the better programmer you are. You cannot be sure unless you check or write a jquery-reference agnostic code. So - in general they don't have to be the same, but may me the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),

a code example on that page is written as:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

so yes, they should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.ajax` and `$.ajax` are the same thing. The dollar sign is an alias for `jQuery` functions.  In some cases, where other js files are using the dollar sign, it is necessary to use `jQuery`. Otherwise, the selector is ambiguous and errors will be thrown in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same.  See the docs for details:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Some libraries such as prototype also use `$` for their own purposes.  jQuery can be put into [noconflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to handle situations where you have another library on the same page that also uses `$`.  In that case they would be different things.